# Format option in vue-datetime wrong format

Tags: datetime, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm using `vue-datetime` plugin, it appears as if the `format` option doesn't work as expected, see below:

```
<datetime type="date" v-model="formData.testDate" input-class="form-control" format="DateTime.DATE_SHORT"></datetime>
```

It should output as: `DD/MM/YYYY` but instead outputs as a random string of characters.

[image]

Comment: You've specified a format string of `'DateTime.DATE_SHORT'`. Literally that string of 19 characters. So the `D` gives the date, the `a` gives the `AM`, the `t` gives the time, the `e` is just passed through... and so on.

Answer (score 3):

Use `datetime` format.
For example:

```
<datetime type="datetime" v-model="datetime13" format="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"></datetime>
```

Answer (score 1):

From the `vue-datetime` [documentation here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-datetime), It states that you need to use `luxon` and `weekstart`. Make sure you install the two packages like this `npm install --save luxon vue-datetime weekstart`.

Register your `DateTime` package globally or locally

**Globally**

```html
import { Datetime } from 'vue-datetime';
 
Vue.component('datetime', Datetime);
```

**Locally**

```html
import { Datetime } from 'vue-datetime';
 
Vue.extend({
  template: '...',
  components: {
    datetime: Datetime
  }
});
```

This `vue-datetime` use `luxon` to set date formats

```html
<template>
<div>
  <datetime type="date"
  v-model="formData.testDate"
  input-class="form-control"
  :format="{ year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' }">
  </datetime>

  <!-- Or use this -->

  <datetime type="date"
  v-model="formData.testDate"
  input-class="form-control"
  format="dd/MM/yyyy">
  </datetime>

</div>    
</template>

<script>
import { Datetime } from 'vue-datetime';
export default {
    data(){
        return {
            formData: {
                testDate: ''
            }
        }
    },
    components: {
        datetime: Datetime
    }
    
}
</script>
```

I hope my answer will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to apply a format to a string. The format should bind to a variable, the variable needs to reference the wanted format option of the DateTime module of luxon.

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <datetime type="date" v-model="formData.testDate" input-class="form-control" :format="format" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { DateTime } from 'luxon';

export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: {
  },
  data: () => ({
    formData: {
      testDate: '',
    },
    format: DateTime.DATE_SHORT,
  }),
}
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the luxon

```
npm install --save luxon
```

and

```
import { DateTime } from 'luxon';
...
//yourDateFromForm = '2019-06-27T11:06:00.000Z'
console.log(DateTime.fromISO(this.yourDateFromForm).toFormat('DD/MM/YYYY'))
```